# How to test if a database updated/See what's inside?(PostgreSQL, Django)

Tags: python, database, django, postgresql

I'm currently trying to code a a simple website where what you submit to the website is is validated and then saved into a database using this bit of code.

```
def referral_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CashtextsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('Submitted_page.html')
    else:
        form = CashtextsForm()
        return render_to_response('CashTextsubmit.html')
```

It works fine (I think) but when i run a Cashtexts.objects.all() on it. The database only returns 2 items from the database even tho I have "submitted" tens of things through the actual web interface.

I really have zero knowledge of Databases so I'm not sure if this is normal or if I'm looking in the wrong place or what is really going on here. any help is appreciated.

Edit: here is the file of Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Cashtexts(models.Model):
    cashcode = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cashcode

class CashtextsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cashtexts
```

Comment: Please post the definition of `CashtextsForm`

Comment: alight I posted it hopefully that helps some.

Comment: First thing I'd check is whether the database has been set up correctly: What's in your `DATABASES` in `settings.py`?

Comment: When you say "web interface", are you talking about the admin or this form that you have created?

Comment: the form. I go to the page (http://127.0.0.1:8000/CashTextsubmit/) in chrome that  shows the form and I submit something and it brings me to the "yay you thing has been submitted" page. then I wrote this Cashtexts.objects.all() into a function and template told it to display that onto the webpage. <br />

and I went through the database set up that was in the book and it set up with zero errors. I'll browse it over again. also everytime I want to use the web app from my computer do I have to somehow "activate" the database? or is that what is being accomplished through the seetings.py file?

Comment: @burhan i edited it hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1):

you can try debugging like

- Try [Django Shell](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api) option ,so that you can check what's going wrong while saving the object
- Another check is that if you are aware of [SQL query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) you can check directly into database exact how many values getting store

Hope it will help you.

Comment: hmmph. thanks for the help. What more would you need to know in order to better help me? or were you saying something different in your header?